# How to set JVM heap size at run time when running jmeter in distributed testing using docker

Tags: jmeter

I have below test infrastructure:

1. 3 instances (master + 2 slaves), dockerized
2. Run command from jmeter master (default 512m is used in all 3 machines) `sudo docker exec -i master /bin/bash -c "/jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/jmeter -n -t /home/librarian_journey_Req.jmx -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=yy.yy.yy.yy -Dclient.rmi.localport=60000 -R1xx.xx.xx.xx -j jmeter.log -l result.csv"`

the above command works fine and getting results also. however wanted to increase the heap size to 3gb at run time.

I had tried using below command:

```
sudo docker exec -i master /bin/bash -c "JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m" /jmeter/apache-jmeter-3.1/bin/jmeter -n -t /home/librarian_journey_Req.jmx -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=10.135.104.138 -Dclient.rmi.localport=60000 -R10.135.104.135,10.135.104.139 -j jmeter.log -l result.csv"
```

after running the above command nothing happens. Please guide how can it be increased.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override environment variables when running containers. Also, usually you don't need to use `sudo` to execute docker. So try this:

```
docker exec -i -e JVM_ARGS="-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m" master /bin/bash ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for guiding, it helped a lot, able to use the command. 1. will this be applicable for both master and slave machines (JVM) 2.  I tried to see if this is being used by using ps -ef| grep jmeter, is there any other way to see if this has been updated or being used. Thanks again.

Comment: Use Debug Sampler” set option: JMeter properties to true

Comment: Thank you. I am running in non gui mode by disabling debug sampler also on aws instances. will this jvm_args applicable for both master and slave machines at run time? Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all help and guidance from all. Able to set heap size to master and slave machines by setting ENV variable at docker jmeter base image as below. Thanks to @vins.
ENV JVM_ARGS -Xms3G -Xmx3G